# Decrease and Increase Enum value

Tags: java, enums

I would like to create a method called increaseValue, which it's signature is as following:

```
public Size increaseValue(Size s)
```

Also I have the following statement:

```
protected enum Size {XS, S, M, L, XL}
```

I need to know, how can I make the method return correct value (i.e. XL when input is L... etc.) while not using Switch-Case statement ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could assume they are in increasing `ordinal()` order.

Comment: @Prabu it is XL when input is L... increase value...

Comment: @Prabu what else would you expect?

Comment: @DimaSan, No Dima, this is not duplicate. I want implementation less complicated than the one on that thread...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could assume they are in increasing `ordinal()` order. I would add this a method on `Size`.

```
protected enum Size {
    XS, S, M, L, XL;
    static final Size[] VALUES = values();
    public Size incrementSize() { return VALUES[ordinal()+1]; }
    public Size decrementSize() { return VALUES[ordinal()-1]; }
}
```

Note: I wouldn't assume that XS is after XL, but rather you get an error (though not a very clear one)

Note: every time you call `values()` it creates a new array. It has to do this because the array is mutable and you might change it.  I highly recommend saving a copy and avoid calling `values()` each time.

You can make the error messages clearer by overriding those methods.

```
protected enum Size {
    XS {
        public Size decrementSize() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No smaller size"); }
    }, 
    S, 
    M, 
    L, 
    XL {
        public Size incrementSize() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No larger size"); }
    };
    static final Size[] VALUES = values();
    public Size incrementSize() { return VALUES[ordinal()+1]; }
    public Size decrementSize() { return VALUES[ordinal()-1]; }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you call `decrementSize()` for `XS`. Wouldn't that result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, an error, you could add a more meaningful one, or a dummy value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name have added a way to have a more meaningful error message without having to use a condition check.

Answer (score 1):

In good OO design you want to **internalize** such things. Meaning: you want to provide a method like "nextSize()" within that enum, like:

```
public enum Size {
  XS, ...;

 public Size nextSize() {
   switch (this) ...
```

In this situation, the values are probably "fixed"; but in other situations, you might later want to **insert** new constants; thus I prefer an *explicit* mapping here; instead of relying on calls to `ordinal()`.

And as mentioned in the other answers: you need to define what `largestSize().nextSize()` means. It could throw an exception, or return null (baaad idea). Alternatively, that method could return `Optional<Size>`; to make it clear to the caller that this method doesn't always return a **valid** result.

Comment: but ordinal will still be function even if a new constant will be added, isn't it ?

Comment: Sure. But it requires you to **write** down your constants in the order you want them to have. That is a subtle detail that a person that changes your enum 6 months later might not be aware of. "Huh, we need some constant Y in enum E" ... to forget that X should go here "X Y Z" and not "X Z Y".

Answer (score 1):

Here's why you should not do it: if you perform arithmetic on your enum, you can end up with invalid values, for instance what would happen if you added one to XL?

Here's how you do it:

```
Size.values()[s.ordinal()+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Size increaseValue(Size s) {
   Size[] allValues = Size.values();
   var newOrdinal = s.ordinal() + 1;
   return (newOrdinal >= allValues.length) ? null) : allValues[newOrdinal];
}

public Size decreaseValue(Size s) {
   var newOrdinal = s.ordinal() - 1;
   return  (newOrdinal < 0) ? null : values()[newOrdinal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Size increaseValue(Size s) {
    return Size.values()[s.ordinal() + 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You van modify this enum like this:

```
  protected enum Size {
   XS,(1) 
   S(2), 
   M(3), 
    L(4), 
    XL(5);

private int sizeNo;

 Size(int sizeNo) {this.sizeNo = sizeNo;} 


 Size getBySizeNo(int sizeNo){
     for(size : Size.values()) {
     if (sizeNo == size.getSizeNo() ) {
     return size;
} 
} 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException() ;
} 

public Size increaseValue(Size s){
       return getBySizeNo(s.getSizeNo() +1) ;
      } 
 }
```